# Make user submited content safe. Escaping HTML in Java (JSP)

Tags: java, html, jsp, escaping, sanitization

I want to make my website safe from XSS attacks or from users submitting HTML in the comments section. I want to make all submits of HTML 'unsafe' and to escape them except for one tag which I use to highlight code submits via javascript (it makes code pretty). The concept is called HTML sanitization. I want only `<pre>` tags to be safe.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_sanitization

Comment: You're probably trying to re-invent Markdown.  Use a Markdown converter; this is much harder than you think.

Comment: @SLaks +1 there's a lot involved in printing HTML, especially if it comes from external sources. Not the least of which is making sure that all tags which are opened are eventually closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [OWASP Sanitizer](https://code.google.com/p/owasp-java-html-sanitizer/wiki/GettingStarted) you can create a policy that only allows `<pre>` tags through:

```
// Define the policy.
Function<HtmlStreamEventReceiver, HtmlSanitizer.Policy> policy
    = new HtmlPolicyBuilder()
        .allowElements("pre")
        .toFactory();

// Sanitize your output.
HtmlSanitizer.sanitize(myHtml, policy.apply(myHtmlStreamRenderer));
```